# How to bind ObservableCollection<LineSeries> to Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpftoolkit

I have a litle problem with Chart binding. 
Is it possible to have a dynamic number of series for a WPF toolkit line chart?

I found many examples how to do it manualy.

For example If I have something like:

```
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="chart_Distribution" Title="Chart Title">
```

And Model like:

```
public class Test : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<LineSeries>  _lineSeries = new ObservableCollection<LineSeries>();                   
    public ObservableCollection<LineSeries> LineSeries
        {
            get { return _lineSeries; }
        }
    private void Test()
        {
            var collection = new ObservableCollection<RequestsInProcess>();
            var collection2 = new ObservableCollection<RequestsInProcess>();

            collection.Add(new RequestsInProcess(0, 4));
            collection.Add(new RequestsInProcess(1, 1));
            collection.Add(new RequestsInProcess(2, 4));
            collection.Add(new RequestsInProcess(3, 3));

            collection2.Add(new RequestsInProcess(0, 3));
            collection2.Add(new RequestsInProcess(1, 2));
            collection2.Add(new RequestsInProcess(2, 2));
            collection2.Add(new RequestsInProcess(3, 1));

            var lineseries1 = new LineSeries();
            lineseries1.IndependentValuePath = "AmountOfRequests";
            lineseries1.DependentValuePath = "Time";
            lineseries1.Title = "Line series1";
            lineseries1.ItemsSource = collection;
            Charts.Add(lineseries1);

            var lineseries2 = new LineSeries();
            lineseries2.IndependentValuePath = "AmountOfRequests";
            lineseries2.DependentValuePath = "Time";
            lineseries2.Title = "Line series2";
            lineseries2.ItemsSource = collection2;
            Charts.Add(lineseries2);

            collection2.Add(new RequestsInProcess(4, 4));
            collection.Add(new RequestsInProcess(4, 4));

        }
}
```

How can I Bind my chart to ObservableCollection?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good solution to this on the following blog post:

http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/351/Silverlight-Charts-Binding-multiple-Series.aspx

Colin E.

Comment: Maybe It's good solution, but I cannot understand What is "DynamicSeries" type? Does it exist in WPF? I cannot use it... If you have any ideas, I'll be pleasure. Senks.

Comment: Replace DynamicSeries with DataPointSeries

Comment: And *that* is why we don't like link only answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: Expired link! Never depend on a link in your answer!